# Is it possible to just add tags to CloudFormation stack after it is created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to just add tags to existing CloudFormation stacks ?
In update stack operation there is away to specify new tags, but is it possible to do it without update (Just like any other resources in AWS) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot add tags to the existing CloudFormation stack without updating the stack.

When you add new Tags to CloudFormation, stack will go to   `UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS` state and updates the wewly added tags to all the supported resources in the stack. Updating/Adding tags will not replace the resources. However, I recommend you to check the Resource Tag Properties, before Updating.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

You can create change set with previous template, review the changeset (look out for scope as tag only in the resource description of changeset), and then execute the change set. For example:

```
aws cloudformation create-change-set --stack-name test--change-set-name test --use-previous-template --parameters file://test.parameters  --tags Key=TestKey,Value=TestValue --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

aws cloudformation describe-change-set --stack-name test --change-set-name test

```
aws cloudformation execute-change-set --stack-name test --change-set-name test
```